# Parenthesis and the Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider sets $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{4,5\}$.  I know that the Cartesian product $A\times B$ is equal to:
$$\{(1,4),(1,5),(2,4),(2,5)\}$$

How would one compute $A\times B \times B$?  Is this different than computing $(A\times B) \times B$?  Is it valid to have one element of an ordered pair be an ordered pair?  I can imagine $(A\times B) \times B$ being
$$((1,4),4),((1,4),5),((1,5),5)\ldots$$ but that looks rather odd to me at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written for $(A\times B)\times B$ is correct. To compute $A\times B \times B$ is almost the same, except you can remove the parentheses you accrued when writing $(A\times B)\times B$.

We generally do not differentiate between the two sets because we tend to study how sets behave under a certain algebraic structure, rather than the set itself. To given an example, if we write $\mathbb R^3 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, then we can also write  $\tilde{\mathbb R}^3 = \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R$. And we do not distinguish between $\mathbb R^3$ and $\tilde{\mathbb R}^3$. This is because if we define addition on each set by $(x_1,y_1,z_1)+(x_2,y_2,z_2) = (x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)$, and $((x_1,y_1),z_1)+((x_2,y_2),z_2) = ((x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2),z_1+z_2)$, then both sets, with respect to addition, behave identically the same, and the difference is purely cosmetic. We can also define some other operations similarly, making these two sets into a vector space, and it is easily shown these two sets are, more or less, the same.

The fancy way to say this is $\mathbb R^3$ and $\tilde{\mathbb R}^3$ are equal up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

$A \times B\times B$ would give 3-tuples.

If $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{4,5\}$ then we have:

$A \times B\times B = \{(1,4,4), (1,4,5), (1,5,4), (1,5,5), (2,4,4), (2,4,5), (2,5,4), (2,5,5)\}$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Taking Cartesian products of sets you cannot apply associative law.
Your interpretation of $(A×B)×B$ is correct but it's not equal to $A×B×B$ due to the aforementioned reasons.